# VLOOKUP Text that is not unique - Excel

Tags: excel, text, vlookup

I am trying to vlookup (bring back) all the products that are yes, but only the first result keeps coming back because the vlookup gets stuck on the first piece of data.

I am using much more data than the range below but please see below as example.

```
A1 = Yes B1 = Product 1
A2 = Yes B2 = Product 2
A3 = Yes C3 = Product 3

=vlookup("Yes",$A$1:$C$3,2,false)
```

It works if I take out the $ signs but then I just get repeat values.

I am guessing this needs a different function but am unsure what to use.

Thanks

Ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this link](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3381-excel-extract-unique-values-with-criteria.html) and understand how that formula works. In your example, put this formula into cell **D2** and **press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER** and fill down using mouse:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$1:$B$12, MATCH(0,IF("yes"=$A$1:$A$12,COUNTIF($D$1:D1, $B$1:$B$12),""), 0)),"")
```