# Vlookup skipping a row in Excel

Tags: excel, vlookup, multiple-instances

I am trying to do a vlook with a base that has lots of different names in this base:

[image]

And I want to do with the criteria `"SICOOB"` in the column `"SISTEMA"`
But when I try this:

```
 =INDEX(Dados!$C$2:$C$100000;
 SMALL(INDEX((Dados!F2:F100000=Relatório!$R$6)*(ROW(Dados!F2:F100000)-ROW(Dados!$F$2)+1););
 CONT.SE(Dados!F2:F2;"<>"&Relatório!$R$6)+ROWS(Dados!C$2:C2)))
```

for some reason it returns number, I dont understand why. I want to return the column `CNPJ`. 
I want to have this result:

```
68987
315406
429890
512839
694389
694877
```

Comment: Do you want an array value from column CNPJ which has same row with SICOOB? Please, write your wish briefly

Comment: Thank you for the reply, edited my description. I want a column CNPJ that has rows ehit SICOOB, exctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VLOOKUP Text that is not unique - Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487435/vlookup-text-that-is-not-unique-excel)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already answered question similar to [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40487435/vlookup-text-that-is-not-unique-excel)

Anyway put into cell `A2` this formula and press **`CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Dados!$C$2:$C$100000, MATCH(0,IF(Relatório!$R$6=Dados!$F$2:$F$100000,COUNTIF($A$1:A1, Dados!$C$2:$C$100000),""), 0)),"")
```

Comment: I had seen this answer but, for some reason, I was doing something wrong. Sorry for the duplicated question and thank you for your help